# Detecting Bixolon SRP-275 Pos Printer using c# (Microsoft Point Of Service)

Tags: c#, pos-for-.net

Somehow my console app can't find the SRP-275 POS Printer that I've already setup. 
Since, this is my first time working with POS Printer, please bear with me.

Below are my steps:

1. Install Bixolon SRP-275 Windows Driver
2. Install Bixolon SRP-275 OPOS Driver
3. Download and Install Pos.Net V 1.12
4. Plug The Printer into the LAN Network.

Then in my code, I reference the Microsoft.PointOfService (From the Pos.Net I've installed), and try finding the PosPrinter using code like this:

```
PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer(this);
DeviceCollection devices = posExplorer.GetDevices();
```

I then try to see whether my Printer is listed in one of the device, and it is not. How can I access my printer from my code, is there any step I do wrong?

NB: I can see my printer installed on the control panel

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

I configure the OPOS Driver from Bixolon printer and it now recognize it, thanks.

Comment: hello, can you please post you code, i need your help

Comment: In this issue I resolve it using the OPOS driver. Not code related.